# How to customize Chakra's Alert and Badge components?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I'd like to extend/customize Chakra's Alert and Badge components so I can do something like this:

Extended Badge component:

```
export const AlertBadge = ({icon, label}) => {
  return (
    <Badge>{/*...*/}</Badge>
  );
}
```

Then I want to use that extended badge inside my alert together with other already existing components:

```
<Alert status="success">
  <AlertBadge icon={<SomeIcon />} label="Badge text" />
  <AlertTitle>Title</AlertTitle>
  <AlertDescription>Lorem ipsum</AlertDescription>
</Alert>
```

I guess I would need to alter the Alert's behavior as well.

```
import { Alert as ChakraAlert } from '@chakra-ui/react';

export const Alert = ({/*...*/} => {
  return (
    <ChakraAlert>
      {/*some customization probably needs to happen here*/}
    </ChakraAlert>
  );
}
```

The most important thing - I want to make the connection between the Alert's status and the Badge's colorScheme, so that my custom badge has the same color as its Alert parent. For example, if the Alert's status is "success", I want the badge to be green. If it's "error", the color should be red, etc.

I'm stuck right now, no idea how to start...

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the badge theme passing Alert status by props:

something like this:

```
const baseStyle = (props: any) => {

  let colorScheme = ''
  switch (props.status) {
    case 'info': {
      colorScheme='purple'
      break
    }
    case 'warning':
      colorScheme='yellow'
      break
    case 'error':
      colorScheme='red'
      break
    case 'success':
       colorScheme='green'
      break
  }

  return definePartsStyle({ colorScheme })
}

export const badge = defineMultiStyleConfig({
  baseStyle,
  defaultProps: {
    colorScheme: 'purple',
  },
})
```